# Animation Drawable under Button

Tags: android, xml, android-animation, android-button, animationdrawable

I've searched around stack overflow and yet am still having trouble with this issue.

i want to display a `Button` on my app, using an `AnimationDrawable` as my background. I followed the Android Dev page (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) and was able to get the animation working. However, my button is entirely hidden. The user can still click it, but the background animation visually hides it, as if there is no button.

I have tried `setAlpha`, but applying it to my 'AnimationDrawable' blurs the 3 images in my `Drawable` "roll of film". Also, the screen starts from black and takes a long time to gradually reach the set opacity. It looks at first that it is a memory issue, but as of now, my app is just one `Activity` with a `Button` that leads to another `Activity`.

Does anyone know how to make my `Button` appear on top of my `AnimationDrawable`? Or does anyone have experience with `setAlpha` slowing down your animation?

Here is my code for reference:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
Button start;
Intent intent= new Intent();
ImageView background;
AnimationDrawable animation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    background= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagehost);
    background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
    animation= (AnimationDrawable) background.getBackground();


    start= (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        ...


} //end of onCreate

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    animation.start();
    //animation.setAlpha(50); //doesn't help

}//end of onWindowFocusChanged
```

**EDIT**

layout xml (main.xml) code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagehost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />
```

animationdrawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnd1" 
    android:duration="600" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnd2" 
    android:duration="600" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnd3"
     android:duration="600" />   


</animation-list>
```

Comment: Can you show us your layout xml ?

Comment: why dont you apply animated drawable to a button bg?

Comment: @Leonidos can you please elaborate? would that button background only be the background of the button? i want my animationdrawable to be fullscreen, and the button not. is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the position of `<Button>` and `<ImageView>`. Elements added later in a `RelativeLayout`, each element's z-index is determined by the order which it was added to the container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >     

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagehost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />  
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i did not know that about relativelayout. unfortunately my app force closes. logcat throws me this error:

"Unable to start Activity Component Info...java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android widget.ImageView"

any ideas?

Comment: Double check the ids on the xml. You mixed them.